# Tailwind css is not applied while I build and deploy my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

I'm facing an issue where the Tailwind CSS styles are not being applied when I build and deploy my React app. I suspect there might be a problem with my Tailwind config file, index.css file, or PostCSS file.

Here are the code snippets for each file:

Tailwind config file (**`tailwind.config.js`**):

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,tsx}"],
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: "media",
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: "transparent",
      current: "currentColor",
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.gray,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      green: colors.green,
      blue: colors.sky,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      purple: colors.purple,
      pink: colors.pink,
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

index.css file:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

html {
  font-family: Inter, ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue',
    Arial, 'Noto Sans', sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
}

/* Other custom styles */
.wave {
  /* Animation styles */
}

/* Other custom styles */
```

PostCSS config file (**`postcss.config.js`**):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

I have installed Tailwind CSS and its dependencies correctly in my React app. When I run the app locally using **`npm start`**, the Tailwind styles are applied correctly. However, after building the app with **`npm run build`** and deploying it to a production environment, the Tailwind styles are not visible on the deployed site.

I have already checked for any error messages or warnings during the build process, but I didn't find any related to Tailwind CSS. Additionally, I have tried running **`serve -s build`** to serve the built app, but the issue persists.